# Stop running nodemon via Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, mocha.js, nodemon

Here's the idea, I would start an app with specific port using nodemon then run my tests, and finally stop the running app so I could run it again anytime.

```
gulp.task('test', function(cb) {
    nodemon({
        script: 'server.js',
        env: { 
            'NODE_ENV': 'test' 
        }
    });

    // Run tests....

    
    // Stop the application and exit running Gulp -> How to do this?
});
```

Is there a way to stop or force ctrl+c the running gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it with these

```
require('shelljs/global'); // https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

gulp.task('test', ['nodemon-test', 'mocha-test']);

gulp.task('nodemon-test', function(cb) {
    nodemon({
        script: 'server.js',
        env: { 
            'NODE_ENV': 'test' 
        }
    })
    .on('start', function() {
        cb();
    })
});

gulp.task('mocha-test', ['nodemon-test'], function() {
    exit(1);
});
```